# google plus API shows less activities than site

Tags: google-plus

My API call with maxResults=8 returns just 6 items, whereas on the googleplus site search there are clearly more results.
Also when setting the max-results up to like 20 i get more results.

So why am i just receiving six items, when there would be 8 possible?

My call:
    https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=gamescon&key=mykey&orderBy=recent&maxResults=8&fields=items(actor(displayName),kind,object(attachments(content,image(type,url),url),content,objectType),published,title,url,verb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ API guarantees that the number items in the response will not exceed the requested `maxResults`, but it doesn't guaranteed that many results in the response. If a `nextPageToken` field is available in the first page of results, use that for an additional page of results.

You need to capture the `nextPageToken` field in JSON response. Take this page token, and make another request with that `pageToken`.

Example, make a request for:

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=gamescon&key=mykey&orderBy=recent&maxResults=8&fields=nextPageToken,items`

Response:

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "xyz",
 "items": [
   ...
 ]
}
```

Take the `nextPageToken` in that response and include it in your next request as the `pageToken` query parameter.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=gamescon&key=mykey&orderBy=recent&maxResults=8&pageToken=xyz&fields=nextPageToken,items`

Comment: well alright i guess i just set the maxResults up and limit it later, thanks for your answer